# jQuery tabs don't work in Internet Explorer but in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-chrome

I need some help with a web application I'm building. 
I'm using jQuery tabs. I have two pages, index.aspx and login.aspx. You start on the index page and when you log in you come to the login page.
If I'm running Google Chrome the tabs are working on both pages. But if I'm running IE the first page (index.aspx) works perfectly, but when I come to login.aspx the program breaks and jumps to the JavaScript file and there stops.

In the JavaScript file I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = 'key';
    var dataStore = window.sessionStorage;
    try {
        var oldIndex = dataStore.getItem(index);
    }
    catch (e) {
        var oldIndex = 0;
    }
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        active: oldIndex,
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
            dataStore.setItem(index, newIndex)
        }
    });
});
```

It first stops at the bottom function and if I press continue it stops at the top function.
The error message I get is  'Object doesn't support this property or method'

login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Projekt.login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" runat="server">
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="content">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
      </div>

 <div id="tabs-2">
       </div>

  <div id="tabs-3">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>   
</div>


<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" style="height: 81px; top: 0px; left: -1px;">
          </div>
</div>

<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
                 </div>
</div>

</form>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="JSprojekt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep it simple, I'm new to this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery 2.x doesn't support IE<10

you likely don't need both jquery includes anyway, just remove it.